# How would you make a UISegmentedControl with a double-tap recognizer on each segment?

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder, uisegmentedcontrol

I tried using InterfaceBuilder to we the touchDownRepeat of my UISegmentedControl to an IBAction in its parent viewController, but the IBAction never fires no matter how many times in a row you tap on the UISegmentedControl. Why do they show this output from the UISegmentedControl in the pop-up menu in InterfaceBuilder, if it does nothing? How do you make it do what it's supposed to do? (Sorry if this is a noob question.)

Also, can each segment of the UISegmentedControl be directly referenced as an object? How about subclassing thereof? If not, why not, and what's a good workaround?

I want to have it where double-tapping a segment will launch a view for editing the mode represented by that segment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I finally figured out this solution. Subclass the UISegmentedControl. Inside there:

```
- (customUISegmentedControl *)init {
    NSTimeInterval interval = 0.0;
    _lastSameTouchTime = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval];
    return self;
}
+ (BOOL)isIOS7 {
    static BOOL isIOS7 = NO;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        NSUInteger deviceSystemMajorVersion = [[[[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
        if (deviceSystemMajorVersion >= 7) {
            isIOS7 = YES;
        }
        else {
            isIOS7 = NO;
        }
    });
    return isIOS7;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSInteger previousSelectedSegmentIndex = self.selectedSegmentIndex;
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    if (![[self class] isIOS7]) {
        // before iOS7 the segment is selected in touchesBegan
        if (previousSelectedSegmentIndex == self.selectedSegmentIndex) {
            // if the selectedSegmentIndex before the selection process is equal to the selectedSegmentIndex
            // after the selection process the superclass won't send a UIControlEventValueChanged event.
            // So we have to do this in here.
            NSTimeInterval diff = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:_lastSameTouchTime];
            _lastSameTouchTime = [NSDate date];
            if(diff <= 1.0)
                NSLog(@"doubletapped!");
            diff = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:_changedTime];
            if(diff <= 1.0)
                NSLog(@"doubletapped!");
        }
        else {
            _changedTime = [NSDate date];
        }
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSInteger previousSelectedSegmentIndex = self.selectedSegmentIndex;
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    if ([[self class] isIOS7]) {
        // on iOS7 the segment is selected in touchesEnded
        if (previousSelectedSegmentIndex == self.selectedSegmentIndex) {
            NSTimeInterval diff = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:_lastSameTouchTime];
            _lastSameTouchTime = [NSDate date];
            if(diff <= 1.0)
                NSLog(@"doubletapped!");
            diff = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:_changedTime];
            if(diff <= 1.0)
                NSLog(@"doubletapped!");

        }
        else {
            _changedTime = [NSDate date];
        }
    }
}
```

Basically now replace the code `NSLog(@"doubletapped!")` with code that does whatever needs to happen when the doubletap has occurred :D And of course declare the relevant NSDate properties for _changedTime and _lastSameTouchTime.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you add `UIButtons` on top of the segmented controls? You can detect the double tap on them with `UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat` and then manually select the segmented control with this:

`- (void)setEnabled:(BOOL)enabled forSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segment`

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)initTouchesRecognizer{
    DLog(@"");
    recognizer = [[UIGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    DLog(@"");

    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
    for (UITouch *touch in allTouches) {

    }
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   DLog(@"");
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

This is the code for a gesture recognizer. Gesture recognizers are designed for UIViews, so really you can only have one gesture recognizer type per view. You can use single tap, double tap, triple tap, swipe, etc. all for different things on the same page but getting two of the same type to do two different things is a feat because they weren't designed to work like that. You should use buttons, like the previous answer said. I was trying to do the same thing and ended up using buttons instead, which turned out to be way more convenient. Even if you could get the gesture recognizer to work the way you wanted, it's very difficult and tedious. The code for a UIButton is WAY shorter.

**EDIT**
The gesture recognizer is typically used for things like making the keyboard disappear when the UIView is tapped; things like that. It's not supposed to be used as a set of custom buttons on a page.

**EDIT #2**
this is how you get it to recognize the gesture so that it calls the appropriate functions:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
    [self.view addSubview:button];
    UIGestureRecognizer *swipe=[[UIGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:button     action:@selector(detectSwipe)];
    [button addGestureRecognizer:swipe];
}
```

you have to initialize it and tell it where to go.